# I wanna make strncpy function directly, can you review my code? There is bus Error

Tags: c, bus, strncpy

I wanna Make `strncpy` function by code, not by using Library or Header

but There is zsh bus error..... What's wrong with my code? What's the zsh bus error??

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char    *ft_strncpy(char *dest, char *src, unsigned int n)
{
    unsigned int    i;

    i = 0;
    while (i < n && src[i])
    {
        dest[i] = src[i];
        i++;
    }
    while (i < n)
    {
        dest[i] = '\0';
        i++;
    }
    return (dest);
}

int main()
{
    char         *A = "This is a destination sentence";
    char         *B = "abcd";
    unsigned int  n = 3;

    printf("%s", ft_strncpy(A, B, n));
}
```

Comment: `A` and `B` point to read only memory, the zsh bus error is probably a segfault because your are trying to write to read-only memory.

Comment: @Joseph: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 3):

Your code exposes one of the *very subtle* differences in `C` between an array and a pointer. The line:

```c
char *A = "This is a destination sentence";
```

declares `A` as a pointer to a character (string) and then initialises that pointer to the address of a **string literal**. This string literal is a **constant** value, and the compiler is allowed to place this in an area of memory that is *read-only*. Then, when you pass that memory to the `ft_strncpy` function (*via* its address), you are attempting to modify that read-only memory.

If you, instead, use the following:

```c
char A[] = "This is a destination sentence";
```

then you are declaring `A` as an **array of characters** and initializing that array with the data *from* the string literal. Thus, the compiler is now aware that the array is *modifiable* (you haven't included a `const` qualifier) and will place that array in memory that can be read from **and** written to.

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation of `strncpy` is fine, the uncanny semantics of the error prone function are correctly implemented (except for the type of `n`, which should be `size_t`).

Your test function is incorrect: you pass the address of a string constant as the destination array, causing undefined behavior when `ft_strncpy()` attempts to write to it. String constant must not be written to. The compiler may place them in read-only memory if available. On your system, writing to read-only memory causes a bus error, as reported by the shell.

Here is a modified version with a local array as destination:

```c
int main()
{
    char          A[] = "This is a destination sentence";
    const char   *B = "abcd";
    unsigned int  n = 3;

    printf("%s\n", ft_strncpy(A, B, n));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Oh my god...! So, there is a difference between *A and A[]...?!! really thank you

Comment: Acutally,I havent know know about the memory which is not written able or read only or something like that... thank you so much

Comment: @Joseph: `const char *B = "abcd";` defines a pointer `B` initialized with the address of a constant array of 5 bytes containing the values `'a'`, `'b'`, `'c'`, `'d'` and `0`. Conversely, `char A[] = "This is a destination sentence";` defines `A` as an actual array of 31 bytes initialized upon entering the `main` function to the values that compose the string `This is a destination sentence` and a null terminator. A pointer is a variable that contains an address whereas a character array is an object that contains actual characters.